# Need to sed awk or grep output to extract strings

Tags: bash, sed, awk, special-characters, escape-characters

I have output which looks like this:

```
"vancouver/news/vancouver-voices": {
    "status": 0,
    "time": 0,
    "timestamp": 1371298701
},
"vancouver/news/vancouvers-march-second-annual-success": {
    "status": 0,
    "time": 0,
    "timestamp": 1371298701
}
```

I need to extract just the partial URLs (`vancouver/news/vancouvers-march-second-annual-success and vancouver/news/vancouver-voices` for example)

I'm basically calling a command via bash and then piping it to grep awk or sed

If I use grep (`| grep -o '".*": {'`) I can get close. I end up with output like:

```
"vancouver/news/vancouver-voices": {
"vancouver/news/vancouvers-march-second-annual-success": {
```

I suspect I need to use sed or awk though. I've tried several things but I think I need to escape some of the special characters. For instance I tried `| awk '\"(.*)\": {' --output='$1`' but it barfs because of the backslashes.

Can any sed or awk guru out there clue me in on how I properly escape the special characters?

Comment: This seems to do the trick although I have to imagine there is a more elegant way of doing this: | grep -o '".*": {' | sed 's/\(^"\|": {$\)//g'. If anyone has any better suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '/{/ {print $2}' FS='"'
```

Result

```
vancouver/news/vancouver-voices
vancouver/news/vancouvers-march-second-annual-success
```

However this would be better done
[using jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq)

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/{/s="\([^"]*\)".*=\1=p'
```

`grep` + `cut` :

```
grep '{' | cut -d'"' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use grep:

```
| grep -o '[^"/]\+\(/[^"/]\+\)\+'
```

yields:

```
vancouver/news/vancouver-voices
vancouver/news/vancouvers-march-second-annual-success
```

It searches for an initial string of non-", non-/ characters, followed by one or more sequences consisting of a slash followed by the same type of string as the initial. One could also use an alphanumeric-plus-dash character class to select the URL components.

Comment: FYI, the -o flag tells grep to print only the part of line that matches the RE.